# Views Grid Display Images Thumbnail Sequently using jQuery

Tags: views, javascript

I am trying to make an image catalog using views grid. This is what I have done so far.

Created a views grid and gave the *test* class to each `<td>`.

```
tr class="row-1 row-first">
 <td class="col-1 col-first test">
 <td class="col-2 test">
 <td class="col-3 test">
 <td class="col-4 test">
 <td class="col-5 col-last test">
</tr>
```

Then I added my custom Javascript to my .info module file. This works since I can confirm it by viewing the page source.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/menara/sites/all/themes/angela/js/custom.js?mii0ef"></script>
```

These are the contents of my `custom.js` :

```
(function($){
var lis = $('.test').hide(),    i = 0;

(function displayImages() {
        lis.eq(i++).fadeIn(200, displayImages);
})();
})(jQuery);
```

When I open Mozilla Firefox there is no Javascript error and the effects are not working.

Please guide me to solve this problem. I am following this [great tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-display-elements-sequentially-with-jquery/).

Regards,

mbahlol

UPDATE

aha i found it. this is what i do, based on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956424/jquery-not-working-on-my-drupal-page)

```
(function ($) {
$(function(){
var lis = $('.test').hide(), i = 0;
(function displayImages() {
    lis.eq(i++).fadeIn(800, displayImages);
})();               
})
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if your jQuery file is properly called, if its called than you can add jQuery.noConflict(); first and than replace $ sign with jQuery.

Comment: thanks @Fahad for respond my question. my problem solve by following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956424/jquery-not-working-on-my-drupal-page